# Issue connecting to private_pub faye server from angular ionic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ionic-framework, faye

I have a rails chat application and a Faye server running, both using [private_pub](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub). Chat messages are successfully being published/subscribed to in this setup. And because of the way private_pub is setup, authentication is built right in.

On a separate server, I'm running an ionic application (using angular) which is trying to connect to the Faye server. However, I can't seem to subscribe to/publish anything, even though the 2 are handshaking (as confirmed by the faye server log).

Some code:

```
# Faye server: private_pub.ru
# Run with: rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
require "bundler/setup"
require "yaml"
require "faye"
require "private_pub"

# Only load rails environment if required
# we are calling sidekiq so it is required
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

PrivatePub.load_config(File.expand_path("../config/private_pub.yml", __FILE__), ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development")
# run PrivatePub.faye_app

# UPDATED CODE - 
# added functionality in gem
app = PrivatePub.faye_app

# subscribe - online
app.bind(:subscribe) do |client_id, channel|
  puts "Client subscribe: #{client_id}:#{channel}"
end

app.bind(:handshake) do |client_id|
  puts "Client handshake: #{client_id}"
end

run app
```

Mobile client side:

```
# services.js
.factory('Faye', function() {
  client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye')
  return client
})


# controllers.js
.controller('ConversationsCtrl', function($scope, Conversations, $location, Faye) {

  var subscription = Faye.subscribe('/**');

  subscription.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
  })

  ...

})
```

As mentioned, the client is successfully handshaking with the faye server, but unable to subscribe (and I can't find error messages anywhere). My guess is that private_pub isn't able to authenticate the client correctly, but I don't know how to fix that. Been scratching my head over this for a while, any help/pointers would be much appreciated! :D

Comment: What's that code? Is it Angular 2?

Comment: v1.something I believe!